# Remove WRITETIME of a Cassandra column

Tags: cassandra

**Background:**

So a machine has a mis-configured date-time to be 2017 (instead of 2016), and Cassandra ran for a day.  After the date-time was corrected, the WRITETIME of many fields are still 2017, and all INSERT/UPDATE would failed silently.

**Question:**

Is there any way to remove/clear WRITETIME?  Or better yet, fix the entire DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're facing the "write barrier" issue. 3 possibles solutions:

1. trash your DB and rebuild it from scratch, brute force solution, not recommended if you do not have a backup of your data
2. use `sstable2json` to convert data files to JSON, fix the timestamp and use `json2sstable` to recreate back data files. It may cost you a lot of time and effort to do the parsing of timestamp
3. use Apache Spark to read from the current tables and write to a new table (same name) but in a different keyspace. Look at this source code sample: https://github.com/doanduyhai/Cassandra-Spark-Demo/blob/master/src/main/scala/usecases/MigrateAlbumsData.scala#L58-L60

Comment: I was trying to use `sstable2json` but I found it too tedious.  In the end, I found a bit easier method.  Use `COPY` command.  There are minor quirk (null vs empty), but for the most part, it works for my database with less than 1000 entries.